# Why is GHC complaining about wrong type?

Tags: haskell, types, compiler-errors, brainfuck

This little function checks a (finite) Brainfuck string for validity. It check's whether the `[` and `]` are balanced. The code is very straightforward and written to be tail-recursive:

```
-- checks Brainfuck for validity.
validateBrainfuck :: Monad m => String -> m String
validateBrainfuck s = maybe (return s) (fail . fromJust) (validate s 0) where
  validate :: String -> Int -> Maybe String -- Here inversed: String means error
  validate (']':_ ) 0 = Just "Too many closing brackets"
  validate (']':xs) c = validate xs (pred c)
  validate ('[':xs) c = validate xs (succ c)
  validate ( x :xs) c = validate xs       c
  validate []       0 = Nothing
  validate []       _ = Just "Too many opening brackets"
```

Now, GHC complains about typing issues:

```
Brainfuck.hs:62:58:
    Couldn't match expected type `Maybe String'
           against inferred type `[Char]'
      Expected type: Maybe (Maybe String)
      Inferred type: Maybe String
    In the third argument of `maybe', namely `(validate s 0)'
    In the expression:
        maybe (return s) (fail . fromJust) (validate s 0)
```

Maybe I'm just too silly to figure out what went wrong, but this looks very weird for me.

Comment: Also, how about `Either String ()` as the type signature?  Then you are not reversing well-defined semantics.  Also, Either is a Monad (well, sort of... see `Control.Monad.Error`), so you don't even have to `fail`.

Comment: I want to have the type signature as universal as possible. So I did this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Look at the type of `maybe` and think what it should do:

```
maybe :: b -> (a -> b) -> Maybe a -> b
```

If the maybe value contains no result (i.e. `Nothing`), `maybe` returns the `b` argument.

*Otherwise* - when `Just a` is given - it applies the given function to the *valid result*. We don't need any `fromJust` extraction here.

Your code just becomes

```
maybe (return s) fail (validate s 0)
```